# How to get file from resources directory from groovy jar library

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy, jar, resources

I'm not being able to read a `JSON` file within `resources` directory from my project's compiled jar.

But... first things first:

I've created a 'Gradle Groovy' Project within Intellij idea (v2017.3.4 Community Edition) with the following structure:

[image]

So, as you can see, I just have a `Main.groovy` class and a `resources` folder inside `src/main` directory.

Inside `resources` directory I've a single resource `db/products.json`.

By going into `File > Project Structure > Modules > Project Module > Sources` menu we can check that `src/groovy` folder is marked as `Sources` and `resources` folder is marked as `Resource Folder`, so I can assure that this folders are correctly set on `classpath`:

[image]

On my Main class I've added following code line to load `/db/products.json` resource:

[image]

By running the Project within Intellij idea I can check that the resource is loaded seamlessly:

[image]

Great! But...

### Now the catch!

When I compile project with `gradle` - through `gradlew build` command - the jar lib `ReadJSONResourceFile-1.0-SNAPSHOT` is generated inside `build/libs` folder.

Looking at the jar's structure, we can check that `db` resource folder is at the jar's root location:

[image]

But when I execute the jar through command:

`groovy -cp build/libs/ReadJSONResourceFile-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -e "org.company.demo.Main.main()"`

the resource is not successfully loaded. `getResource()` just returns `null`:

[image]

I've been trying to workaround this with other solutions provided here on `Stack Overflow`but neither of them worked.

I'm missing something here... can you help?

Comment: you are calling `getClass()` in a static method. maybe that's the problem?

Comment: It should be `getClass().getResource("/db/products.json")`.  Does `getResource` accept a Map as an argument?

Comment: Yes @dagget, I believe that's the problem. 
I've created a `Java` application (instead of a groovy one) and when I typed `getClass()`, Intellij idea warned me right away that I can not call `getClass()` inside a `static method`.

I then created a Singleton class to wrap `getClass().getResources()` call and things started to work just fine (runing app both through the IDE and through the jar)

Comment: @abdul that's not a map inside `getResource()` arguments... it's just Intellij idea's intellisense in action! :)

Comment: you can use `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` annotation for groovy class to have static validation

Comment: good tip @daggett! Thanks for your help

Comment: @dagget, late answer here :)
You were right. The problem was the `getClass()` call inside the `main` static method. Making the call inside a `non-static method` works as expected.
Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077548/learn-java/java-tip-49--how-to-extract-java-resources-from-jar-and-zip-archives.html I was able to use that class to load an image (jpg) from Resources using groovy.